# difference between toggleclass and addclass

Tags: jquery, addclass, toggleclass

I am working with jquery and attempting to add a class to a table on the selection of that table row.

I was initially using the following code -

```
$(this).parents("tr").toggleClass("over", this.clicked);
```

For some reason, that wasn't working in *only some* instances where there was already a class assigned. 
Before I went too crazy with any troubleshooting, I changed it to the following -

```
$(this).parents("tr").addClass("over", this.clicked);
```

This new option appears to be working fine.

My question is whether one option above is better than the other.....Should I be using toggleClass instead of addClass, or is addClass sufficient?

thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`addClass` does just that, adds the class to the element.

`toggleClass` on the other hand does THAT, toggles the class, removing it if it's there, otherwise adding it, but optionally taking a boolean value (true/false) to determine if the object should be added (true) or removed (false).

`toggleClass` probably wasn't working for you in the instances where `this.clicked` was `false`, which is expected behavior. The argument you're passing in `addClass` has no effect, since it ALWAYS adds the class.

Conclusion:

Use `toggleClass` for toggling classes, use `addClass` for adding classes.

Answer (score 4):

If `addClass` is working for you, then you should stick with it. The methods are meant for different purposes. `addClass` ensures that a particular class is present on an element, while `toggleClass` adds the class if it isn't there and removes it if it is.

Check out the API reference for the full explanation of each method:

- http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/
- http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to pass a second argument to .addClass() - it will always add the class.

If that's the behaviour you want, that's the right method.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that the second argument is unnecessary... I removed it and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Depends really. If you don't plan on removing the class, I'd stick with `addClass`. Naturally, `toggleClass` allows you to toggle classes.

Comment: I am actually going through and removing the particular class for all rows in the table before I add it onto the row that is selected.  Therefore, I think that just addClass will accomplish exactly what I need.  Thanks