# tick to be displayed button on button and to reduce its opacity when it's clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like for a tick to be shown and its opacity reduced on a button once it is clicked.

```css
#btnTicketType{
    margin-bottom:2%;
    margin-top:10%;
    width:95%;
    height:15em;
    font-size:1.5em;
}

#seatnumber{
    display:block; 
    width:100%; 
    text-align:center;
    font-size:1em;
}

#rectangle{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    outline-color:black;
    outline-style:solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="rectangle">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <button id="btnTicketType" class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button>
            <small id="seatnumber">Text 1</small>
        </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
            <button id="btnTicketType" class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button>
            <small id="seatnumber">Text 2</small>
        </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
            <button id="btnTicketType" class="btn btn-default">Button 3</button>
            <small id="seatnumber">Text 3</small>
        </div>
}
</div>
<br />
```

It would be nice if also to reduce the opacity of the button once the tick shows so that the tick would be more prominent for the user.

Comment: You should use an Element, besides a `<button></button>` or `<input type='button' />`, as buttons don't support `.innerHTML`. Either that or use `position:absolute;` on the button and the tick in and have the parent of the both, `position:relative;`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Button color onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937424/change-button-color-onclick)

Comment: @PHPglue What does the question have to do with `innerHTML()`? A `<button>` tag can contain other elements, such as the tick that Op is after. Semantically speaking, a `<button>` element is more suitable than a `<span>` (or whatever element you might recommend).

Comment: You want a tick in the button. You cannot put anything in a button.

Comment: hmm, thanks chiru. I'll look into the link and see what i can do

Comment: @PHPglue `<button>This is <strong>valid</strong> HTML</button>` because a [buttons can have content](https://css-tricks.com/use-button-element/#article-header-id-1). So, based on that, you can add an `<img>` tag inside a `<button>` element, or could potentially use [Font Awesome icons](http://fontawesome.io/icon/check/) to add a tick icon. I used the `<span>` tag as an example, but a `<div>` is still semantically incorrect. Regardless, I'm simply saying a `<button>` is a suitable tag here.

Comment: @shikiko I've posted an answer showing how to add elements to a `<button>` tag. I've also added several links for MDN that point where the above comments from @PHPglue are incorrect, such as _"anything within a `<button>` is `.value`"_. The value comes from the `value` attribute: `<button name="foo" value="this is the value">This is what the user sees on screen</button>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a HTML/CSS/JavaScript snippet that does the following things:

1. Includes a 'tick' on each button; and
2. Once a button is clicked, it fades out

**You can see a working example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p1nuhd2t/8/).**

Your question is a tad confusing, as the question title and body say different things:

> Display Tick on button and **reduce opacity when its clicked**

Versus:

> I would like for **a tick to be shown on a button once it is clicked**.

The CSS for this snippet can be easily modified to achieve either result.

## Working Snippet

```js
$( '.btnTicketType' ).click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('clicked-button');
});
```

```css
.btnTicketType {
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    width: 95%;
    height: 15em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.seatnumber{
    display: block; 
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
}

#rectangle{
    overflow: auto;
    outline-color: black;
    outline-style: solid;
}

.clicked-button {
    opacity: .1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.7.0/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rectangle">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <button class="btnTicketType btn btn-default" value="">
            <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            Button 1
        </button>
        <small class="seatnumber">Text 1</small>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <button class="btnTicketType btn btn-default" value="">
            <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            Button 2
        </button>
        <small class="seatnumber">Text 2</small>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <button class="btnTicketType btn btn-default" value="">
            <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            Button 3
        </button>
        <small class="seatnumber">Text 3</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

## Additional Notes

1. A `<button>` element is [semantically valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button):

   > The HTML `<button>` element represents a clickable button.
2. A `<button>` element [can contain other HTML elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Notes) if required:

   > `<button>` elements are much easier to style than `<input>` elements. You can add inner HTML content (think `<em>`, `<strong>` or even `<img>`), and make use of `:after` and `:before` pseudo-element to achieve complex rendering while `<input>` only accepts a text value attribute.
3. Based on the above definitions, I've used [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) to add the [check icon](http://fontawesome.io/icon/check/) to your buttons.
4. Your HTML incorrectly reused ID attributes. An `id="btnTicketType"` attribute must be unique, and cannot be reused in valid HTML. If you need to style multiple elements, it's better to use a `class="btnTicketType"` instead. I replaced the repeated ID attributes with classes instead for the HTML in my snippet.
5. If you're using the `<button>` element in a `<form>`, the `value=""` attribute will be submitted with the form. From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-value):

> **`value`**
>   The initial value of the button. It defines the value associated with the button which is submitted with the form data.  This value is passed to the server in params when the form is submitted.

Comment: thanks for providing so much informative sources for me to refer too. I would just like to ask regarding the Jquery statement that calls the CSS to reduce its opacity to .1. Is there a way I can re-click and it will revert the opacity back to normal ?

Comment: @shikiko You can use [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) instead of `addClass()`. You can learn about the differences here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342396/difference-between-toggleclass-and-addclass

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it. I think i can manage it now somewhat